What will be the overleaf code for this table
[![Estimated effects of ribavirin compared with no treatment on mortality outcomes from studies][1]][1] This is cation of table
This is table link [1]: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9328902/figure/F4/
This is research paper link https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9328902/
The latex code i have right now is this:
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % for \mathbb
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz} % for drawing diagrams
\usepackage{soul}% for underlines
\usepackage{changepage,threeparttable} % for wide tables
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[width=150mm,top=35mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}




\newcommand{\errplot}{%

\begin{tikzpicture}

[trim axis left,trim axis right]

\begin{axis}[y=\baselineskip,

  ymax=22.4,

  ymin=0,

  axis y line*=middle,

  y axis line style=dashed,

  ytick=\empty,

  axis x line*=bottom]
\addplot+[only marks][error bars/.cd,x dir=both, x explicit]
coordinates
 {
(0.03,12)+-(0.86,-1.7)

(0.02,11)+-(0.9,-0.81)

(0.13,10)+-(0.69,-0.49)

(0.10,9)+-(0.7,-0.1)

(0.10,8)+-(0.72,0.88)

(0.10,7)+-(0.7,0.04)

(0.04,6)+-(0.68,-0.75)

(1.53,5)+-(0.53,-1.13)

(0.92,3)+-(0.54,0.1)

(0.94,2)+-(0.55,-1.31)

(0.53,1)+-(0.54,-0.3)

};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}%

}

\res

\begin{table}[h!]

\centering 

\caption{Estimated effects of ribavirin compared with no treatment on mortality outcomes from studies.
}
\label{table:ribavirin_effects}

\begin{tabular}{c c c c c} 

\toprule

& &Ribavirin &No Ribavirin & Odds \\ 

Study & & Deaths\

/Total & Deaths\

/Total & Ratio (95\% CI) \\

\midrule

Ajayi,2013 & \multirow{22}{7cm}{\errplot} & 1/7 & 3/3 & 0.03(0.00 to 1.04) \\

Asogun,2012 & & 41/148 & 12/12 & 0.02(0.00 to 0.27) \\

Buba,2018 & & 6/19 & 22/28 & 0.13(0.03 to 0.47) \\

Dahmane,2014 & & 8/20 & 14/16 & 0.10 (0.02 to 0.54) \\

Lior,2019 & & 69/334 & 15/21 & 0.10 (0.04 to 0.28) \\

Joseph,2019 & & 7/43 & 2/3 & 0.10 (0.01 to 1.22) \\

Orji,2020 & & 4/21 & 3/3 & 0.04 (0.00 to 0.85) \\

Price,1988 & & 12/55 & 2/13 & 1.53 (0.30 to 7.89) \\

Samuels,2020 & & 23/38 & 5/8 & 0.92 (0.19 to 4.43) \\

Shaffer,2014 & & 44/74 & 14/23 & 0.94 (0.36 to 2.46) \\

Wauguier,2020 & & 29/61 & 7/11 & 0.53 (0.14 to 2.02) \\[4ex] 
       
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}

But problem is that when i run this, the dotted line is exceeding from below along with nodes, how do i solve this error

Welcome! I'm afraid the site isn't an image-to-code service. In the vast majority of cases, you'll only get effective help if you provide code (a minimal but complete document) showing what you've tried and explaining what problem you're having. Also, questions should not rely on external links because their content may change. If you really need to include an image, you will need to upload it here (which you should only do if legally permitted, of course).

Please don't vote down new users' contributions without even leaving a comment and without giving them any opportunity to improve their posts first! Less than 10 minutes, 0 comments and 1 down-vote? :(

I've provided the code and its error , kindly reopen the question

@MaryamZaman Please have a look at minimal working example (MWE). The code should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Welcome to TeX.SX. A "Minimal Working Example" (MWE) starts with \documentclass, includes all relevant \usepackage commands, ends with \end{document} and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

@SandyG I've edited it now. i want to insert a table in my thesis, but I couldn't set the dotted line with scale properly , the dotted line keep exceeding where it should be

Thanks for your edit. Did you test the code from your questions to check if it compiles?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes it does run, but only issue is with scale line having nodes

The missing \begin{document} and some other problems mean that the code in your question does not compile.

i don;t know how to properly add whole document code here, \begin{document} command is present in my document and my code compiles

We can't see your document. We can only see the code in your question. You need to make sure that the code in your question allows us to reproduce your problem. Please have a look at minimal working example (MWE)

Do you have lines in your real table ending with a single backslash? If so, either remove them or use add a second backslash to end the row of a tabular, for example.

Create a new document. Copy your code from this question and paste it into your new document. You will see that the new document doesn't compile. You are missing \begin{document}, and the command \res is not defined. There are some other issues also. Try to simplify your new document as much as possible in a way that still reproduces the error. For example, most of the \usepackage commands are unnecessary.

Your table only has 11 rows of data, so change the value of ymax, and make sure the y-coordinates in your coordinates number from 1 to 11.

\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[width=200mm,top=35mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\newcommand{\errplot}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
        \begin{axis}[y=\baselineskip,
            ymax=11.4,
            ymin=0,
            axis y line*=middle,
            y axis line style=dashed,
            ytick=\empty,
            axis x line*=bottom]
        \addplot+[only marks][error bars/.cd, x dir=both, x explicit]
            coordinates{
                (0.03,11)+-(0.86,-1.7)
                (0.02,10)+-(0.9,-0.81)
                (0.13,9)+-(0.69,-0.49)
                (0.10,8)+-(0.7,-0.1)
                (0.10,7)+-(0.72,0.88)
                (0.10,6)+-(0.7,0.04)
                (0.04,5)+-(0.68,-0.75)
                (1.53,4)+-(0.53,-1.13)
                (0.92,3)+-(0.54,0.1)
                (0.94,2)+-(0.55,-1.31)
                (0.53,1)+-(0.54,-0.3)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering 
\caption{Estimated effects of ribavirin compared with no treatment on mortality outcomes from studies.}
\label{table:ribavirin_effects}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc} 
\toprule
& & Ribavirin & No Ribavirin & Odds \\ 
Study & & Deaths/Total & Deaths/Total & Ratio (95\% CI) \\\midrule
Ajayi,2013 & \multirow{12}{7cm}{\errplot} & 1/7 & 3/3 & 0.03(0.00 to 1.04) \\
Asogun,2012 & & 41/148 & 12/12 & 0.02(0.00 to 0.27) \\
Buba,2018 & & 6/19 & 22/28 & 0.13(0.03 to 0.47) \\
Dahmane,2014 & & 8/20 & 14/16 & 0.10 (0.02 to 0.54) \\
Lior,2019 & & 69/334 & 15/21 & 0.10 (0.04 to 0.28) \\
Joseph,2019 & & 7/43 & 2/3 & 0.10 (0.01 to 1.22) \\
Orji,2020 & & 4/21 & 3/3 & 0.04 (0.00 to 0.85) \\
Price,1988 & & 12/55 & 2/13 & 1.53 (0.30 to 7.89) \\
Samuels,2020 & & 23/38 & 5/8 & 0.92 (0.19 to 4.43) \\
Shaffer,2014 & & 44/74 & 14/23 & 0.94 (0.36 to 2.46) \\
Wauguier,2020 & & 29/61 & 7/11 & 0.53 (0.14 to 2.02) \\[4ex]\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Omg thankyou so much my problem is resolved now

i want to change the dotted line of scale on entry 1 , right now its on 0. plz help me

In general it's better to ask a new question and include a link to this one, rather than ask additional questions in the comments. But I think axis y line shift=-1 is what you're looking for.

I noticed you haven't accepted any answers on any of your questions. On this site, instead of giving thanks in the comments, it is appropriate to upvote all answers you find helpful and accept the answer you think best answers your question. Instructions are here.
